# Change the height of textarea, CKEditor library

Tags: javascript, jquery, size, height, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKEditor and I need to change the size, but this is not the real problem, because I can.  The problem is that when I change the size I can not set data to textarea. I think that the problem is in the size change because when I don't use it, I don't have any problems.

The form that I used to change the size is:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor'+id,{height: "70%"});
editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'editor'+id);
```

It works fine! The problem is when I use `setData()` like this:

```
editor.setData(text); //where text is the data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to have two text boxes? If not, you should use either `CKEDITOR.replace()` or `CKEDITOR.appendTo()` but not both. From the project's [samples folder](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/samples/appendto.html):

> `CKEDITOR.appendTo` is basically to place editors inside existing DOM elements.        Unlike `CKEDITOR.replace` a target container to be replaced is no longer   necessary. A new editor instance is inserted directly wherever it is desired.

If yes, then perhaps `id` is being set to the same value elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I got it!, it is a strange answer but is the "solution" of my problem, thank :D.

Comment: Accept it as the solution, if you would be so kind.